# blank screen with the AMDGPU drivers on a Radeon RX 550 graphics card

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I recently purchased a Radeon RX 550 graphics card to replace the Intel integrated graphics controller on my motherboard. AMD provides both open source and hybrid AMDGPU drivers. I've tested these on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and 17.10.1 and I'm getting blank screens on all of these configurations.

When I attempt the installations with the graphics card installed, the installer screens are not visible. This also prevents me from using  to look at the BIOS settings. So I performed the installation using the Intel integrated graphics controller and then installed the graphics card for testing.

The open source AMDGPU driver is installed by default with either 16.04.3 or 17.10.1. When I attempt to boot either of these releases I get a blank screen with a moveable mouse. Some of the progress screens (“Ubuntu …”) are visible, but not the main desktop or any application window. I'm including some diagnostic info below, including lspci, inxi -G, dpkg, ps aux and some of the Xorg log file. In some of these configurations, I've been able to set my DISPLAY variable to localhost:0.0 to run things like xdpyinfo, but in others I can't seem to reset this variable. But the bottom line is that it seems that the drivers are getting installed and the X server is running. I'm just getting a blank screen.

The behavior with the hybrid driver is a bit different. No moveable mouse, just a blank screen. The diagnostic info is different, but comparable.

I've seen similar questions and the advice was to be very precise about which release you use, which I've tried to follow.

***open source driver***

**17.10**

```
lspci
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Polaris12 (rev c7)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

inxi -G
Graphics:
    Card-1: Intel 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
    Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Polaris12
    Display Server: N/A drivers: i915,amdgpu
    tty size: 80x30 Advanced Data: N/A out of X

dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  1.4.0-1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1             amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver

ps aux | grep Xorg
gdm       1142  0.0  0.9 775960 78160 tty1     Sl+  15:45   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

**16.04.3**

```
lspci
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 699f (rev c7)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

inxi -G
Graphics:
    Card-1: Intel 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
    Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 699f
    Display Server: N/A drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
    tty size: 121x32 Advanced Data: N/A out of X

dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  1.4.0-1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1             amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

***hybrid driver***

**16.04.3**

```
lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 699f (rev c7)

inxi -G
Graphics:
    Card-1: Intel 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
    Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 699f
    Display Server: N/A drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
    tty size: 113x27 Advanced Data: N/A out of X

dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04
1.3.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04          2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1~16.04.1      amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver

ps aux | grep Xorg
root      1475  0.0  1.0 346356 87828 tty7     Ssl+ 22:33   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch

/var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    44.314] (**) ModulePath set to "/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules,/opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    44.328] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
```

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I see very similar issue with AMDGPU and the same set of drivers.

Comment: I am sorry. I never did get that to work and now I have a different desktop system.

Comment: Thanks highpost. It's good to know that.